# (CentOS-6.5) How to implement GNOME environment privilege escalation like GKSUDO?

Tags: centos, sudo, root

How would I implement a `GKSUDO` -like privilege escalation control on CentOS 6.5 workstations? (standard GNOME config, x86_64 and i386)

I do not want to share the root password with users, and some of the applications & commands they use do not work properly -- or at all -- when launching them from a Terminal with `$ sudo <application> <flags>`.

Essentially, I would like to have CentOS 6.5 require authentication for privilege escalation operate pretty much ***exactly*** like Ubuntu/Unity has for some time now.

Comment: @strugee Thanks for the edit; can you explain how the not-root-user tag is not applicable? My question is exactly that; I don't want to give the users the rootpw, so they are *not root users*, but they need to escalate privilege, not "become root".
Also, why is the /CentOS6 tag not relevant?

Comment: it's about usage. generally we use [tag:not-root-user] for questions about when _you're_ not the root user, not implementing this for someone else. and the version of CentOS isn't really important (CentOS is enough). if you want, feel free to roll back - but that's my perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the CentOS wiki, titled: [How To Become Root](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BecomingRoot). The application you're looking for is called consolehelper.

Comment: Thanks @slm. `consolehelper` came up in my previous searches, but the articles were all 10+ years old, and none mentioned PAM **iirc*. I will dig into the PAM doco (ugh) and let you know how it goes. This may be what I need; I'll come back and mark it Answered if so. Much appreciated.